# Explain await Task.Yield in an ASPNET Core WebApi context

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, yield

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20await%20Task,execution%20back%20to%20that%20context.)

*You can use await Task.Yield(); in an asynchronous method to force the method to complete asynchronously. If there is a current synchronization context (SynchronizationContext object), this will post the remainder of the method's execution back to that context. However, the context will decide how to prioritize this work relative to other work that may be pending.*

So I'm expecting that, in a WebApi, I can make use of this in two ways

- My async operation **really** needs to be async and I don't want the internal implementation to return using a synchronous path.
- My async operation is about to do some heavy work but I don't need to block the response to the caller. As a process, I'm "giving up" my execution to the caller and I'm happy to be scheduled later.

But I'm not finding that this is happening my my .NET Core WebApi

```cs
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("GET: Start DoSomethingAsync");    
        await DoSomethingAsync();       
        _logger.LogInformation("GET: End DoSomethingAsync");

        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("DoSomethingAsync: Starting");
        await Task.Yield();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _logger.LogDebug("DoSomethingAsync: Finsihed");
    }
```

I'm expecting "End DoSomethingAsync" to get logged first and "DoSomethingAsync: Completed" to come a second later. I know `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null in this case but should my `DoSomethingAsync` not log AFTER GetWeatherForecast is run?

```
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
info: AsyncTestsApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      Start DoSomethingAsync
dbug: AsyncTestsApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      DoSomethingAsync: Starting
dbug: AsyncTestsApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      DoSomethingAsync: Completed
info: AsyncTestsApi.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      End DoSomethingAsync
```

Comment: You left out the rest of the paragraph: _"The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher than input and rendering work. For this reason, **do not rely on `await Task.Yield();`** to keep a UI responsive. For more information, see the entry Useful Abstractions Enabled with `ContinueWith` in the Parallel Programming with .NET blog."_. I.e. this indicates that `Task.Yield` might not always do what you think it would do, so you might want to look into more rigid methods.

Comment: You are also awaiting DoSomethingAsync(), so you will never see what you are expecting, that is just not how async await works, regardless of you calling Task.Yield().

Comment: Finally, the logger or console output might show things out of order. They're not meant to be accurate measurement devices. I.e. don't solemnly rely on the order shown there. E.g. use timestamping (which also my introduce some delay or locking).

Comment: As already stated `await` enforced to wait till everything within is done. You could probably see some effects if your `Get()` would be called simultaneous from mulitple incoming requests, but also in that case the number of incoming requests has to be higher then the number of threads available within the system to enforce the task scheduler to shift any work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm expecting "End DoSomethingAsync" to get logged first and "DoSomethingAsync: Completed" to come a second later

That is an incorrect expectation; the `await` here:

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("GET: Start DoSomethingAsync");    
await DoSomethingAsync();       
_logger.LogInformation("GET: End DoSomethingAsync");
```

means that the 3rd line doesn't happen until *everything* in `DoSomethingAsync()` has completed *asynchronously if needed*. You can get the behaviour you want via:

```cs
_logger.LogInformation("GET: Start DoSomethingAsync");    
var pending = DoSomethingAsync();       
_logger.LogInformation("GET: End DoSomethingAsync");
await pending;
```

however, this is fundamentally the same as adding a second thread in regular non-async code - you now have two execution flows active on the same request. This *can* be valid, but can also be dangerous if thread-safety semantics are not observed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't see much use for Task.Yield apart from when running in a UI context, and understanding the consequence.
I can launch a hot task with a discard `var _ = DoSomethingAsync()` or more specifically, use `Task.Factory` to control the context in which things are being created.

Answer (score 2):

> in a WebApi, I can make use of this

I can't think of a valid use case for `await Task.Yield();` on ASP.NET. It would cause a thread switch and provide no benefit.

> My async operation really needs to be async and I don't want the internal implementation to return using a synchronous path.

This should never be necessary. On ASP.NET, you don't have an operation that "needs to be async". If it's synchronous, just make it synchronous.

> My async operation is about to do some heavy work but I don't need to block the response to the caller. As a process, I'm "giving up" my execution to the caller and I'm happy to be scheduled later.

On ASP.NET, the response is only sent when the asynchronous method completes. So `await Task.Yield();` (and `await` in general) does not yield to the browser/client; it yields to the caller of the method (or the ASP.NET runtime thread pool if it was invoked by ASP.NET). See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) for more information.

If you need to return early, then you need a [proper distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen comments of Task.Yield() being unnecessary before and needed clarity. I've seen Task.Yield() being used in one project before which led me down this path but this just confirms it was being used incorrectly.

Comment: You may have a long running, CPU-bound, synchronous block of code that you want to run as part of a background task in a hosted service at startup. The BackgroundService base class facilitates background tasks by not awaiting the Task returned by ExecuteAsync, however, as recommended by Microsoft: "Avoid performing long, blocking initialization work in ExecuteAsync". You could do `await Task.Yield();` immediately, ahead of the blocking code, and I feel that would be a valid case.

Comment: @StevenDarby: [I just use `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html), as described on my blog.